# How do I enable Butt Mode?

Tags: shovel-knight

I've heard that Shovel Knight has a secret 'Butt Mode', in which various key nouns in the games text are replaced with 'butt'. How do I enable this?

Comment: ... There are no words.

Comment: ... only butts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To enable Butt Mode, at the start of the game, enter your name as **WSWWAEAW**. After a confirmation prompt, you'll be able to enter your name properly, and then the tale of Butt Butt will commence!

Comment: Shield Butt is best Butt!

Comment: You can also use the code [X&BUTT](https://twitter.com/YachtClubGames/status/484557237331828736)